# Error trying to Populate a MAP in flutter using a JSON from C#

Tags: c#, json, string, flutter, rest

This is the API REST in C# to return a JSON

> public async Task Leer([FromForm] string token)  {
> try
> {
>
> ```
>  string jsonResultado = await Clases.AccesoDatos.JsonData("SELECT * FROM vistatransacciones");             
>            jsonResultado= jsonResultado.Substring(1);
>            int longitud = jsonResultado.Length - 1;
>            jsonResultado = jsonResultado.Substring(0,longitud);               
>             string simple = "'";
>             string dobleComilla = "\x022";
>             string json = jsonResultado.Replace(simple,dobleComilla);                
>             return Content( json,"application/json" );
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>
>             return BadRequest(ex.Message);
>         }
>     }
> ```

This is the OUTPUT from de API REST
{"idRegistro":"4","idUsuario":"1","FechaRegistro":"2023-01-25T00:00:00","FechaGasto":"2023-01-25T00:00:00","TipoGasto":"OTRO","TipoTransaccion":"otro","Descripcion":"test","Monto":"3222.00","Nombre":"XXXXX","Ruta":"C:\DocumentosGastoApp\coin_dollar_money.ico","Pagado":false,"nota":"Nada"}

This the MAP:
{idRegistro: 4, idUsuario: 1, FechaRegistro: 2023-01-25T00:00:00, FechaGasto: 2023-01-25T00:00:00, TipoGasto: OTRO, TipoTransaccion: otro, Descripcion: test, Monto: 3222.00, Nombre: XXXX, Ruta: C:\DocumentosGastoApp\coin_dollar_money.ico, Pagado: false, nota: Nada}

This is the flutter code to read de JSON:

```
  final Map<String, dynamic> productsMap = json.decode(resp.body);
  productsMap.forEach((key, value) {
    final tempProduct = Product.fromMap(value);
    tempProduct.id = key;
    products.add(tempProduct);
  });
```

This is the flutter error msg:

_TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')

This is the model in flutter:

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<Product> productFromMap(String str) =>
    List<Product>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Product.fromMap(x)));

String productToMap(List<Product> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toMap())));

class Product {
  Product({
    this.idRegistro,
    this.idUsuario,
    this.fechaRegistro,
    this.fechaGasto,
    this.tipoGasto,
    this.tipoTransaccion,
    this.descripcion,
    required this.monto,
    this.nombre,
    this.ruta,
    required this.pagado,
    required this.nota,
    this.id,
  });

  bool pagado;
  String? idRegistro;
  String? idUsuario;
  String? descripcion;
  String? nombre;
  String? ruta;
  DateTime? fechaRegistro;
  DateTime? fechaGasto;
  String? tipoGasto;
  int monto;
  String? tipoTransaccion;
  String nota;
  String? id; //Esto es opcional pues el id no existe al momento de la creacion

  factory Product.fromJson(String str) => Product.fromMap(json.decode(str));

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Product.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Product(
        idRegistro: json["idRegistro"],
        idUsuario: json["idUsuario"],
        fechaRegistro: DateTime.parse(json["FechaRegistro"]),
        fechaGasto: DateTime.parse(json["FechaGasto"]),
        tipoGasto: json["TipoGasto"],
        tipoTransaccion: json["TipoTransaccion"],
        descripcion: json["Descripcion"],
        monto: json["monto"],
        nombre: json["Nombre"],
        ruta: json["ruta"],
        pagado: json["pagado"],
        nota: json["nota"],
        id: json["idRegistro"],
        //picture: json["picture"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "idRegistro": idRegistro,
        "idUsuario": idUsuario,
        "FechaRegistro": fechaRegistro,
        "FechaGasto": fechaGasto,
        "TipoGasto": tipoGasto,
        "TipoTransaccion": tipoTransaccion,
        "Descripcion": descripcion,
        "Monto": monto,
        "Nombre": nombre,
        "ruta": ruta,
        "Pagado": pagado,
        "nota": nota,
      };
```

I give up, i got not idea

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could know at which line you have Error but i guess it is at this line:

```
final tempProduct = Product.fromMap(value);
```

fromMap argument is Map but you are passing the values of your response map to fromMap. it is like you have this item in your map: `"idRegistro":"4"` and you pass `4` to fromMap. i wish i could explain it well in text. but your problem is that you are not passing your complete json Map to fromMap.

imagine that this is your response:

```
var map = {
"idRegistro":"4",
"idUsuario":"1",
"FechaRegistro":"2023-01-25T00:00:00",
"FechaGasto":"2023-01-25T00:00:00",
"TipoGasto":"OTRO",
"TipoTransaccion":"otro",
"Descripcion":"test",
"Monto":"3222.00",
"Nombre":"XXXXX",
"Ruta":"C:\DocumentosGastoApp\coin_dollar_money.ico",
"Pagado":false,
"nota":"Nada"
};
```

as you see your map size is 1.
and by this code you are filling your list:

```
 var products = <Product>[];
          final tempProduct = Product.fromMap(map);
          products.add(tempProduct);
```

if you had a list of map something like this:

```
var map = [
{
"idRegistro":"4",
"idUsuario":"1",
"FechaRegistro":"2023-01-25T00:00:00",
"FechaGasto":"2023-01-25T00:00:00",
"TipoGasto":"OTRO",
"TipoTransaccion":"otro",
"Descripcion":"test",
"Monto":"3222.00",
"Nombre":"XXXXX",
"Ruta":"C:\DocumentosGastoApp\coin_dollar_money.ico",
"Pagado":false,
"nota":"Nada"
},

{
"idRegistro":"4",
"idUsuario":"1",
"FechaRegistro":"2023-01-25T00:00:00",
"FechaGasto":"2023-01-25T00:00:00",
"TipoGasto":"OTRO",
"TipoTransaccion":"otro",
"Descripcion":"test",
"Monto":"3222.00",
"Nombre":"XXXXX",
"Ruta":"C:\DocumentosGastoApp\coin_dollar_money.ico",
"Pagado":false,
"nota":"Nada"
}

];
```

you would do this:

```
 var products = <Product>[];

for(var item in map){

    final tempProduct = Product.fromMap(item);
          products.add(tempProduct);

}
```

because `item` is the map you should pass to the fromMap.

note to edit fromMap to this:

```
  factory Product.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      Product(
        idRegistro: json["idRegistro"],
        idUsuario: json["idUsuario"],
        fechaRegistro: DateTime.parse(json["FechaRegistro"]),
        fechaGasto: DateTime.parse(json["FechaGasto"]),
        tipoGasto: json["TipoGasto"],
        tipoTransaccion: json["TipoTransaccion"],
        descripcion: json["Descripcion"],
        monto: json["Monto"],//here changed from monto to Monto
        nombre: json["Nombre"],
        ruta: json["ruta"],
        pagado: json["Pagado"],//here changed from pagado to Pagado
        nota: json["nota"],
        id: json["idRegistro"],
        //picture: json["picture"],
      );
```

because you don't have `monto` and `pagado` as lowerCase in your json and it is `Monto` and `Pagado`.

if you had any question, i'm here to help you my friend.

happy coding...

Comment: Thanks a lot, Thanks to everybody, specially to Amirali, that was the soluction

Comment: you're welcome bro, if this answer was helpful and was your answer please vote and mark it as correct answer to help another people when they have this question